# Got message response from Outlook Mail REST API without "Sender" or "From" fields

Tags: outlook-restapi

When requesting messages through GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages got 2 messages that doesn't have field Sender or From

I tried $select param but it has no effect

This field is critical for our application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you GET /me/messages, you get messages from all folders in the mailbox, including the Drafts folder. Draft messages do not have `Sender` or `From` set.

You should be able to check the `isDraft` property to check if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks this was the case